# Python how to get rid of lowercase elements inside a list

Tags: python, list, lowercase

This is my current code:

```
def poisci_pare(besedilo):        
    sents = besedilo.split('.')
    noviseznam = [sent.split() for sent in sents if sent]
    return noviseznam
```

This returns:

```
poisci_pare("You are cool Anna. Johnny and I.")
>>>output: [["You", "are", "cool", "Anna"], ["Johnny", "and", "I"]]
```

how could I change my function so it will delete lowercase words and return lists with only uppercase words? for example I want to accomplish this:

```
poisci_pare("You are cool Anna. Johnny and I.")
>>>output: [["You","Anna"], ["Johnny", "I"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of words with mixed case:

```
words = ["You", "are", "cool", "Anna"]
```

You can exclude the ones that are in lower case with a comprehension:

```
words = [word for word in words if not word.islower()]
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because I have to have a list within a list, I have [["You", "are", "cool", "Anna"]], how would I go on about doing this for a list that's in an existing list?

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have tried:

```
 s = "You are cool Anna. Johnny and I."
 [ re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*',x) for x in s.split('.')[:-1] ]
```

output:

```
[['You', 'Anna'], ['Johnny', 'I']]
```

provided `sentence` always end with '.'

Comment: It sometimes works, but when I put this as a string (this is in Slovene, I have to test with these sentences for my assingment) it didn't work, if you try to put s = 'Na vratih sta se prva pojavila Ana in Peter, menda "slučajno". Peter se je sicer več vrtel okrog Nives.' it returns: [['Na', 'Ana', 'Peter,', 'Peter', 'Nives']]
What's up with that? Could the "" inside the sentence be the problem?

Comment: @NejcPisk Python 2 or Python 3? Byte strings or Unicode strings? Depending on these, the `č` might be the problem too.